# How to add promotional banners in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2

help to add promotional blocks or banners in Magento 2.1 thank you

Comment: Hi, could you please update your question and be a bit more specific: What have you tried? What are you trying to achieve? Did you get any error and if so, what is the error message?

Comment: Many of the same mechanisms are available in Magento 2 as were in Magento 1.

Comment: i have to create promotion rule "Spend $40 & Receive a Shave Brush Free" and am having a banner of same "Spend $40 & Receive a Shave Brush Free" so how i have to create and apply rule to category products